# Using a sortable data structure as DataSource for a DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, datatable, dataview

I was trying to find which C# collection would be suitable for using in a DataGridView. I have considered:

- List: Lookups are O(n). I am looking for a faster one.
- Dictionary: I cannot use it in a DataGridView directly.
- SortedList: SortedList.GetValueList implements IList, but it is read-only.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you limited to just those selections? Why not a `DataTable` with a `DataView` which you can apply a sort to?

Comment: It seems DataTable is not really suitable for fast lookups. Please, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Maybe not the fastest, but if using a `DataGridView`, it is probably the easiest. I suppose it depends on your requirements (and how much code you want to write):  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352792/surprising-performance-differences-list-constains-sortedlist-containskey-dataro

Comment: I agree with @JasonFaulkner: you should try DataView and see how it works, then do a speed optimization upon necessity. Best regards,

Comment: Thanks. OK, a DataTable, even if it's not perfect for my purpose, seems the most convenient. I will stick to a DataTable.

Comment: Best of luck with your project: DataTable should suffice the goal in most cases.